# cannot import keras from tensorflow depending on if there exists a file in the current directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

This is a follow up to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62033587) however this question should be able to stand alone. I get the following error when I try to import tensorflow while there exists a file containing `from tensorflow import keras`.

```
➜  test1 ls
code.py
➜  test1 cat code.py
from tensorflow import keras
➜  test1 python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:33)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 23, in <module>
    from absl.app import run as _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 35, in <module>
    import pdb
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "/Users/mathewlewis/Documents/Y4S3/Crypto/kerasTutorial/testing/test1/code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow import keras
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/activations/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import deserialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import session as session_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import sparse_tensor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/sparse_tensor.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import constant_op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 324, in <module>
    ops.register_tensor_conversion_function(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute 'register_tensor_conversion_function'
>>> exit()
➜  test1 ls
__pycache__ code.py
➜  test1 mv code.py temp
➜  test1 rm -r __pycache__
➜  test1 python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:33)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>>
```

However if I do the same thing while the file is not present, or if the file doesn't have the extension `.py` then I get no error.

```
➜  test2 ls
➜  test2 python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:33)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow import keras
>>> exit()
➜  test2
```

Also, I cannot run the python script without error.

```
➜  test1 ls
code.py
➜  test1 python3 code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow import keras
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 23, in <module>
    from absl.app import run as _run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 35, in <module>
    import pdb
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "/Users/mathewlewis/Documents/Y4S3/Crypto/kerasTutorial/testing/test1/code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow import keras
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/activations/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import deserialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import session as session_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import sparse_tensor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/sparse_tensor.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import constant_op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 324, in <module>
    ops.register_tensor_conversion_function(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute 'register_tensor_conversion_function'
➜  test1
```

I am confused why it is possible for me to import keras from tensorflow via the python interactive interpreter (I'm not sure what the correct name for this is so feel free to change it) while it is not possible for me to do so in a script that I run. Moreover, why should the existence of another file impact my ability to import?

Also, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow like so:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install tensorflow
```

However this didn't fix the problem. All the same issues still occur just as they are documented above.

Also I do not have `keras` installed directly. To be specific, I have not installed keras like so: `pip3 install keras`. That being said, I did install it earlier and all the same problems still occured so I uninstalled it. Through my testing I believe my problem is independent of if I have `keras` installed.

On a related note, I have never had these kinds of problems with any other python library. Keras and tensorflow are the only time I've run into these issues. Are these libraries known for being finicky or is this just me? I have spent quite a few hours at this point trying to get this to work and I am getting close to giving up. I was wondering if there are other machine learning libraries for python.

As requested, here is the result of `pip freeze`:

```
absl-py==0.9.0
arrow==0.15.6
ascii==3.6
astunparse==1.6.3
attrs==19.3.0
blinker==1.4
blis==0.4.1
cachetools==4.1.0
catalogue==1.0.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.3
conda==4.3.16
cryptography==2.9.2
cycler==0.10.0
cymem==2.0.3
docopt==0.6.2
gast==0.3.3
google-auth==1.15.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.29.0
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.9
imageio==2.8.0
importlib-metadata==1.6.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
keras-models==0.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.2.0
Markdown==3.2.2
matplotlib==3.2.1
more-itertools==8.3.0
MouseInfo==0.1.3
murmurhash==1.0.2
np==1.0.2
numpy==1.18.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
opt-einsum==3.2.1
packaging==20.4
pandas==1.0.3
pathlib==1.0.1
pathtools==0.1.2
peewee==3.13.3
Pillow==7.1.2
plac==1.1.3
pluggy==0.13.1
preshed==3.0.2
protobuf==3.12.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
py==1.8.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
PyAutoGUI==0.9.50
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser==2.20
pydash==4.7.6
PyGetWindow==0.0.8
PyMsgBox==1.0.8
pyobjc==6.2
pyobjc-core==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==6.2
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==6.2
pyobjc-framework-AdSupport==6.2
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices==6.2
pyobjc-framework-AuthenticationServices==6.2
pyobjc-framework-AutomaticAssessmentConfiguration==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Automator==6.2
pyobjc-framework-AVFoundation==6.2
pyobjc-framework-AVKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-BusinessChat==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CloudKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ColorSync==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Contacts==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ContactsUI==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudio==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudioKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreBluetooth==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreHaptics==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreMedia==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreMediaIO==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreML==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreMotion==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreServices==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreSpotlight==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN==6.2
pyobjc-framework-CryptoTokenKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-DeviceCheck==6.2
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==6.2
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording==6.2
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecordingUI==6.2
pyobjc-framework-DiskArbitration==6.2
pyobjc-framework-DVDPlayback==6.2
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ExecutionPolicy==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ExternalAccessory==6.2
pyobjc-framework-FileProvider==6.2
pyobjc-framework-FileProviderUI==6.2
pyobjc-framework-FinderSync==6.2
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==6.2
pyobjc-framework-GameCenter==6.2
pyobjc-framework-GameController==6.2
pyobjc-framework-GameKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-GameplayKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ImageCaptureCore==6.2
pyobjc-framework-IMServicePlugIn==6.2
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==6.2
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Intents==6.2
pyobjc-framework-IOSurface==6.2
pyobjc-framework-iTunesLibrary==6.2
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==6.2
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==6.2
pyobjc-framework-libdispatch==6.2
pyobjc-framework-LinkPresentation==6.2
pyobjc-framework-LocalAuthentication==6.2
pyobjc-framework-MapKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-MediaAccessibility==6.2
pyobjc-framework-MediaLibrary==6.2
pyobjc-framework-MediaPlayer==6.2
pyobjc-framework-MediaToolbox==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Metal==6.2
pyobjc-framework-MetalKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ModelIO==6.2
pyobjc-framework-MultipeerConnectivity==6.2
pyobjc-framework-NaturalLanguage==6.2
pyobjc-framework-NetFS==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Network==6.2
pyobjc-framework-NetworkExtension==6.2
pyobjc-framework-NotificationCenter==6.2
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==6.2
pyobjc-framework-OSAKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-OSLog==6.2
pyobjc-framework-PencilKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Photos==6.2
pyobjc-framework-PhotosUI==6.2
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==6.2
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==6.2
pyobjc-framework-PushKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==6.2
pyobjc-framework-QuickLookThumbnailing==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SafariServices==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SceneKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Security==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SecurityFoundation==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface==6.2
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Social==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SoundAnalysis==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Speech==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SpriteKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-StoreKit==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==6.2
pyobjc-framework-SystemExtensions==6.2
pyobjc-framework-UserNotifications==6.2
pyobjc-framework-VideoSubscriberAccount==6.2
pyobjc-framework-VideoToolbox==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Vision==6.2
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==6.2
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyperclip==1.8.0
PyRect==0.1.4
PyScreeze==0.1.26
pytest==5.4.2
pytest-watch==4.2.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyTweening==1.0.3
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.0
ruamel.yaml==0.16.10
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.0
rubicon-objc==0.3.1
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.14.0
spacy==2.2.4
srsly==1.0.2
tabulate==0.8.7
tensorboard==2.2.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.6.0.post3
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
termcolor==1.1.0
Theano==1.0.4
thinc==7.4.0
timeloop==1.0.2
tqdm==4.46.0
urllib3==1.25.9
wasabi==0.6.0
watchdog==0.10.2
wcwidth==0.1.9
websocket-client==0.57.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.1.0
```

Comment: can you post the result of `pip freeze`?

Comment: what is the content of the file?

Comment: I have added the result of pip freeze however I don't know which file you're referring to. If you mean the file `code.py` then to see its content look at the first chunk of code, I cat the file. As you can see the only content is `from tensorflow import keras`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright so this is a bug. I reproduced your issue using the `python` `docker` container, only installing the latest `tensorflow`. What fixed it, was **renaming `code.py` to `test.py`** (or anything else for that matter). This means this this is for sure a `tensorflow` issue. During `import tensorflow`, `python` will for some reason also import your `code.py`. Will you file an issue or should I?

Comment: On a side note - [insert facepalm meme here]

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I thought I was going insane. It's great to have someone else confirm that I have in fact found a bug. If you could file a bug report that would be great. I don't know where exactly to put the report or how to format it so if you are familiar with this sort of thing that would be easier if you don't mind. If you do file one, please post a link to it in your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I filed a bug report. Link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40265

Answer (score 1):

This is not TensorFlow related. In your stack trace, you see:

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
```

I.e. the official Python `pdb` package does `import code`, i.e. it loads the [official `code` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html).

When you start some Python script, it will add the current path to `sys.path` at the very first position. Because of that, you can also not name your script `sys.py`, `os.py`, or the name of any other official Python module.

Comment: Allright I closed the issue on the tensorflow github.